# Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile vs Add-AzureAccount

Tags: powershell, azure

**Introduce the Problem**

I like to manage Windows Azure Websites through PowerShell. For instance, I like to run Get-Website to view a list of all my websites. Before I do that, I need to authenticate with Windows Azure.

**Research**

One way to do this is via [Add-AzureAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495128.aspx), which prompts me to sign in with my Azure username and password, afterwhich I can run Get-AzureWebsite to view the list. At this point, I have no Management Certificates, and it doesn't seem to matter. I can run [Remove-AzureAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495268.aspx) some@account.com to sign out.

[image]

Another way to do this is via a Management Certificate. I run [Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495224.aspx) followed by [Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495124.aspx). Then I can run Get-AzureWebsite to view my list.

This seems like two ways to do the same thing.

**Question**

Other than allowing me to save a Management Certificate for convenience, what is the difference, if any, between the two methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile` is not interactive, so I can use a batch process.

`Add-AzureAccount` is interactive. Since I do not require the certificate, I use `Add-AzureAccount` because it is easier.

Comment: What is an example of a batch process in Windows Azure PowerShell?

Comment: A good example would be continuous deployment scenario wherein you would want to perform unattended deployment. This is where you could use `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile` to automate your deployment.

Comment: Add-AzureAccount can now be called in an unattended manner http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-powershell-0-8-6/